# Is my proof flawed or unclear?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $\mathcal X$ denote the set of all sequences of real numbers, with $d$ a metric on $\mathcal X$. For each $k\in\mathbb N$ let $\vec x_k=(x_{k,n})_{n\geq1}\in\mathcal X$. Prove that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\vec x_k$ exists in $(\mathcal X,d)$ if and only if $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_{k,n}$ exists for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

$``\implies"$ 
Let $\lim_{k\to\infty}\vec x_k=\vec L\in\mathcal X$. This means for each $k\in\mathbb N$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{k,n}=\ell_k$. This is for all $k\in\mathbb N$ and so indeed $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_{k,n}=(\ell_{k,n})_{n\geq1}=\vec L$.

$``\impliedby"$ Since $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_{k,n}$ exists for all $n\in\mathbb N$, we know that $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_{k,n}=\ell_k, \forall n\in\mathbb N$. So indeed $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{k,n}=(\ell_{k,n})_{n\geq1}=\vec L\in\mathcal X$. Well this is an element of $\mathcal X$ so there must be some sequence that converges to this sequence in $\mathcal X$.

It seems this proof is just an obvious direct proof using the definitions. Am I missing some subtlety to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\vec x_k=\vec L$ does *not* (immediately, by definition) tell us that for each $k$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{k,n}=\ell_k$.

The definition of limit in a metric space instead tells us that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $N$ such that for $k \ge N$, $d(\vec x_k, \vec L) < \epsilon$.

So at some point you have to deduce something from properties of the metric $d$. And this is now a place where the question (as you've stated it) is unclear: how *is* $d$ defined? It's not true in general that any metric $d$ will do; for example, I might define $$d(\vec x, \vec y) = \begin{cases}1 & \vec x \ne \vec y \\ 0 & \vec x = \vec y\end{cases}$$ and then the claim in the question is definitely false. There are even more subtle examples, such as $$d(\vec x, \vec y) = \sup_{n \in \mathbb N} |x_n - y_n|,$$ where your property only holds in one direction. (Can you come up with an example of sequences $\vec x_k$ which have no limit with respect to this metric $d$, even though they have a limit in each coordinate?)

So you have to find out what $d$ is. Once we've fixed a definition of $d$, your proof has to go through that definition to get what you want.

Comment: So knowing that $d$ is defined as $d((x_n)_{n\geq1},(z_n)_{n\geq1})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{|x_n-z_n|}{2^n(1+|x_n-z_n|)}$ is not enough? We need to show that $d$ get's smaller than $\epsilon$?

Comment: For the $\impliedby$ direction, yes: for all $\epsilon>0$, you have to show that $d(\vec x_k, \vec L) < \epsilon$ for all sufficiently large $k$. For the $\implies$ direction, you get to assume this, and have to show convergence in every coordinate.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Thanks for your help Misha!

Comment: Do you know what the appropriate action is if I want to update what my proof to indicate what it looks like now, based on your feedback? Should I start a new thread? Should I modify this one? Is it inappropriate to keep asking for help? I'm new and not sure what the best solution is. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it is a substantial change, it is appropriate to start a new thread (while linking to the old one). I think. I've seen people do this, anyway.

Comment: I think that is the appropriate think to do. Thanks for all your help Misha.