# Is my proof flawed or unclear? A follow-up question.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, metric-spaces

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2463360/is-my-proof-flawed-or-unclear) I asked:

Let $\mathcal X$ denote the set of all sequences of real numbers, with $d=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{|x_n-y_n|}{2^n(1+|x_n-y_n|)}$ a metric on $\mathcal X$. For each $k\in\mathbb N$ let $\vec x_k=(x_{k,n})_{n\geq1}\in\mathcal X$. Prove that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\vec x_k$ exists in $(\mathcal X,d)$ if and only if $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_{k,n}$ exists for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

I've since taken the advise of [Misha](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/383078/misha-lavrov) and come up with the following:

$``\implies"$ 
Let $\lim_{k\to\infty}\vec x_k=\vec L_k\in\mathcal X$. This means for all $\epsilon_k>0$, $\exists K$ such that when $k_\epsilon>K$ we have that $d(\vec x_k,\vec L_k)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{|x_k-\ell_k|}{2^k(1+|x_k-\ell_k|)} <\sum^\infty_{k_\epsilon>K}\bar\ell_{k_\epsilon}<\epsilon_k$. Then we can say that $\forall\epsilon_n>0,$ $\exists N$, say $N=k_\epsilon,$ such that when $n_\epsilon>N$, $d\left(x_{k,n_\epsilon},\bar\ell_{n_\epsilon}\right)<\epsilon_n$ since $\bar\ell_{n_\epsilon}$ must stay small as $\vec x_k$ converges to it. That is the coordinates of $\vec x_k$ must converge, we chose $n_\epsilon$ so that $d(x_{k,n},\bar\ell_n)<\epsilon_n\implies\lim_{n_\epsilon\to\infty}x_{k,n_\epsilon}=\bar\ell_k$.

$``\impliedby"$ Since $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_{k,n}=\bar\ell_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, we know that $\forall\epsilon_n>0,$ $\exists N$ such that $n_{\epsilon}>N\implies d\left(x_{k,n},\bar\ell_n\right)<\epsilon_n$. This is for all $n\in\mathbb N$, so indeed we can create $\vec x_k=\left(\bar\ell_{k,n}\right)_{n\geq1}\in\mathcal X$ with the knowledge that $\forall \epsilon_k>0$, $\exists K$ such that $k_\epsilon>K\implies d\left(\vec x_k,\vec L_k \right)<\epsilon_k$ which means $\lim_{k\to\infty}\vec x_k$ exists in $\left(\mathcal X,d\right)$.

Is the notation unclear? Does the $\impliedby$ portion skip over any necessary logical steps?

Comment: This looks like a proof verification question - if so, you should add this tag.

Comment: You should answer your own question belowyour post

Comment: @JohnDoe someone else did it before I got a chance to.

Comment: @GuyFsone Are you suggesting I shouldn't be asking this question and I should already know the answer?

Comment: Yes you should so it does not hinder people to comment. How someone put an answer here?

Comment: How does this question hinder people from commenting? Are you saying my question is unanswerable? I feel like you are not being clear @GuyFsone, perhaps even a bit rude.

Comment: I never said that people will not comment . rather that is the only think there they can do because this is not a proper problem. but and answer. it will be close very soon

Comment: @GuyFsone It's better to have the answer in the question and not in the answers section as the OP is not asking for solutions to his problem but for verification of his solution, and I don't think it'll be closed soon it's a valid question.